# Trying to run migrations in Sinatra but can't load Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm looking to run migrations for a Sinatra app called "sinatra_active_record_start" but can't get my settings right.

When I run `bundle exec rake -T` I get:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sinatra_active_record_start

/Users/jasonnappy/ga_wdi/exisiting_resources/wdi_london/resources/materials/local/06-server-applications/ruby/sinatra/active-record/sinatra_active_record_start/Rakefile:1:in `require'
```

Same as when I run:

```
bundle exec rake db:create_migration first_migration
```

My Gemfile is:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "sinatra"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem "rake"
gem "thin"
```

My Rakefile is:

```
require "sinatra_active_record_start"
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"


namespace :db do
  desc "Migrate the database"
  task(:migrate => :environment) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = true
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("db/migrate")
  end
end
```

The top of `app.rb` is:

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "sinatra"
require "activerecord"
require "sinatra/activerecord"
```

I know there are some redundancies, but at this point, I'm just trying to plug in and make something work that I found on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

First, it doesn't look like you are requiring an adapter for your database. Adding one, like

```
gem "sqlite3"
```

to your Gemfile, should fix that.

Second, `sinatra/activerecord` creates migrations in a directory called "db/migrate" by default. That's where your migrations should live, not the root directory.

Move your migration there and remove

```
require "sinatra_active_record_start"
```

from your Rakefile. That's the code that is causing the immediate error. You shouldn't need to require each migration in the Rakefile.

Following these steps should make your migrations run, although you should rename the file to follow ActiveRecord convention. Run

```
rake db:create_migration NAME='sinatra_active_record_start'
```

to create a new one with a timestamp.

"[Sinatra Active Record Starter Kit](https://github.com/LaunchAcademy/sinatra-activerecord-starter-kit)" is an example repo to help you get started.